# Floating label styling

Tags: html, css, material-design

I am using the CSS found [here](http://codepen.io/boast/pen/pLjld) to make floating form labels. I chose this styling because there is no JavaScript needed and the HTML markup is simple enough (i.e. a `div` with a class and then only a `label` and `input` tag). If there are other simple style sheets available please let me know.

I am a backend developer and I suck at CSS and cannot figure out how to adjust this CSS so it looks nice when:

- There is a select tag (`<select/>` instead of an `<input/>` tag)
- When the background is not white

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
    <form class="float-label" spellcheck="false">
  <legend>Float Label Demo</legend>

  <!-- we need a wrapping element for positioning the label -->
  <!-- the required attribute is ... required! -->
  <div class="control">
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" required />
    <!-- yes, this is not nice, in real live, do it with JS -->
    <label for="title">Title</label>
  </div>

  <div class="control small">
    <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Price" required />
    <label for="price">Price</label>
  </div>
  <div class="control medium">
    <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Specific location (optional)" required />
    <label for="location">Specific location (optional)</label>
  </div>

  <div class="control">
    <textarea name="description" placeholder="Description" required></textarea>
    <label for="description">Description</label>
  </div>

</form>
```

```css
@border: 1px solid #ddd;
@padding: 10px;
@label-font-size: 13px;

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
}

// Demo styles
form {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 2em auto;

  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 22px;

  legend {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: @border;
  }
}


// float label
.float-label {
  .control {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: @border;
    padding-top: @padding + @label-font-size;
    padding-bottom: @padding;

    // you proably want to replace these with your grid classes
    &.small {
      width: 30%;
      border-right: @border;
    }

    &.medium {
      width: 70%;
      padding-left: @padding;
    }

    &:last-child {
     border: 0;
    }
  }

  input, textarea {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    resize: none;

    // inactive but shown label (exceptions: opacity and top)
    & + label {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      transition: top 0.7s ease, opacity 0.7s ease;
      opacity: 0;

      // Some nice styling
      font-size: @label-font-size;
      font-weight: 600;
      color: #ccc;
    }

    // THE MAGIC
    // as soon as we start typing, the "required" attribute will
    // set the state to valid and our pseudo selector will match
    &:valid + label {
      opacity: 1;
      top: 3px;
    }

    // and we highlight the focused input label
    &:focus + label {
      color: #2c8efe;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is what this styling looks like when the background is black:

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "nice"? Also give some specific cases, instead of "not white", can you say what exact color you mean? I'd like to help you, just be more specific.

Comment: Also what do you mean by "when there's a select box"? Are you talking about a `<select>` HTML form element?

Comment: Sorry guys, by select box I mean with a <select> tag instead of an <input> tag. Also by nice I mean, in my example if the background color is black instead of white, it does not look like it should.

Comment: I have attached an image that shows the input box does not look correct when the background is black. I think if the text was just white and the background color was black it would be fine

Comment: Why the down votes? I have provided code and have a clear problem?

Comment: question is opinion based, there is no specific issue you identified

Comment: The issue is clear David, when the background is black the input background shows up white. It would be nice if the input background was the same color as the body background and the text turned white instead of black.

Comment: So you need the background to be black for input fields too. right?

There is no <select> in the code as you mentioned.

Comment: Anyway added few codes in the answer. Just paste it in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: #000;
}
form {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 22px;
}
form legend {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
.float-label .control {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  padding-top: 23px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.float-label .control.small {
  width: 30%;
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
}
.float-label .control.medium {
  width: 70%;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.float-label .control:last-child {
  border: 0;
}
.float-label select,
.float-label input,
.float-label textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  resize: none;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
}

.float-label select + label,
.float-label input + label,
.float-label textarea + label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  transition: top 0.7s ease, opacity 0.7s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #ccc;
}


.float-label select:focus + label,
.float-label input:valid + label,
.float-label textarea:valid + label {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 3px;
}

.float-label select:focus + label,
.float-label input:focus + label,
.float-label textarea:focus + label {
  color: #ccc;
}
option{color:#000;}

input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:active,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #000 inset !important; 
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #ccc !important;
    }
```

```html
<form class="float-label" spellcheck="false">
  <legend>Float Label Demo</legend>
  
  <!-- we need a wrapping element for positioning the label -->
  <!-- the required attribute is ... required! -->
  <div class="control">
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" required />
    <!-- yes, this is not nice, in real live, do it with JS -->
    <label for="title">Title</label>
  </div>
 
  <div class="control small">
    <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Price" required />
    <label for="price">Price</label>
  </div>
  <div class="control medium">
    <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Specific location (optional)" required />
    <label for="location">Specific location (optional)</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="control">
    <select>
    <option>option 1</option>
      <option>option 2</option>
    </select>
    <label for="description">Description</label>
  </div>
  
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You've copied the Less (non-compiled CSS) which will not render properly in browsers - so if you take examples from CodePen in the future keep that in mind :)

**The inputs have a transparent background, which lends itself to any background colour ( or pattern ) so if you change the background colour of the body/parent it will still look good**

This might be what you're looking for:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: #000;
}
form {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 22px;
}
form legend {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
.float-label .control {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  padding-top: 23px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.float-label .control.small {
  width: 30%;
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
}
.float-label .control.medium {
  width: 70%;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.float-label .control:last-child {
  border: 0;
}
.float-label select,
.float-label input,
.float-label textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  resize: none;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
}

.float-label select + label,
.float-label input + label,
.float-label textarea + label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  transition: top 0.7s ease, opacity 0.7s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #ccc;
}


.float-label select:focus + label,
.float-label input:valid + label,
.float-label textarea:valid + label {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 3px;
}

.float-label select:focus + label,
.float-label input:focus + label,
.float-label textarea:focus + label {
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<form class="float-label" spellcheck="false">
  <legend>Float Label Demo</legend>
  
  <!-- we need a wrapping element for positioning the label -->
  <!-- the required attribute is ... required! -->
  <div class="control">
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" required />
    <!-- yes, this is not nice, in real live, do it with JS -->
    <label for="title">Title</label>
  </div>
 
  <div class="control small">
    <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Price" required />
    <label for="price">Price</label>
  </div>
  <div class="control medium">
    <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Specific location (optional)" required />
    <label for="location">Specific location (optional)</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="control">
    <select>
    <option>option 1</option>
      <option>option 2</option>
    </select>
    <label for="description">Description</label>
  </div>
  
</form>
```

Comment: When you select the option from the drop down, it has a yellow background, can you make it so it looks like the standard text background?

Comment: I've updated the code to have a dropdown, is that more what you're after?

Comment: @segFault what browser are you using?

Comment: You have hard coded the text to be white but can you make it change to black when the background isnt black. So white text on non white background and black text on white background? The description drop down is working btw, I was focusing on the title dropdown.

Comment: Title dropdown? that's a browser autocomplete? you cannot change the colouring of this, just disable it if you don't want them to be able to auto complete - and for the colour changing not without using javascript

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your stylesheet :

```
.float-label select,
.float-label input,
.float-label textarea {
  background: transparent;
}
```

And you will get the `<input>`, `<textarea>`and `<select>` with transparent background. So you can change the background color to the color of your choice later without any tension about form field background colors.

Thanks 
*Nabeel*

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer is to change the background-color of the inputs directly.

Something like this;

input { background-color: blue;}

you could copy/paste that right into your CSS and use any color you want. I put this CSS into the following html code at W3schools.com and got this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <form action="">
    User name:
    <br>

    <style>
      input {
        background-color: blue;
      }
    </style>
    <input type="text" name="userid">
    <br>User password:
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="psw">
  </form>

  <p>The characters in a password field are masked (shown as asterisks or circles).</p>

</body>

</html>
```

I hope this works for you!